# Growth of $f'(x)$ and that of $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logarithms, asymptotics

If $f(x)$ is differentiable function in $(0,1)$ with $f'(x)\geq 0$ in $(0,1)$ and $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x}\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \text{as} \ \ x\to 1^-$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ denotes the Big O.

My question is: What will be the behaviour of $f(x)$ as $x\to 1^-$?

I tried using the definition of Big O so that there exists $M>0$ and $x_0$ such that for $x\geq x_0$ $$f'(x)\leq M   \left(\frac{1}{x}\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)  \text{as} \ \ x\to 1^-        $$
Can we say something about the growth of $f(x)$ as $x\to 1^-$?

Comment: Should the extra $\frac{1}{x}$ be really there in the big-O estimate?

Answer (score 1):

First, compute: $$\int_x^1{\frac{\ln{\!\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}}{t}\,dt}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}^2$$  Then we use monotonicity (or, as one Calculus textbook I've seen calls it, "the racetrack principle"): if $$f'(t)\leq g'(t)$$ for all $t\in[x,X]$, then $f(X)-f(x)\leq g(X)-g(x)$.  In our case, $$0\leq f'(t)\leq M\frac{\ln{\!\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}}{t}\tag{*}$$ for $t$ in some region $[x,1]$.  Thus $$f(1)-f(1)\leq f(1)-f(x)\leq\frac{M}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}^2$$ and, rearranging, $$f(1)\geq f(x)\geq f(1)-\frac{M}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}^2$$ on that region.